# I need a function to list all multiples of 3 in the previous output in decending order

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, formatting, pascals-triangle

I'm trying to participate in a coding challenge, and I have part of the code complete, but now I need a function to list all multiples of 3 in the previous output in descending order.

Is there a function you could do that would run all the previous numbers printed in the triangle and divide it by 3,and then print the numbers that came out as a whole number from that calculation? Or some other similar task to come up with all the multiples of 3 up to line 50 in Pascal's Triangle?

```
def generate_pascals_triangle(rows):
    triangle = [[1], [1, 1]]
    if rows == 1:
        return triangle[0]
    else:
        for row_number in range(2, rows):
            triangle.append([1]*row_number)
            for number in range(1, row_number):
                triangle[row_number][number] = (triangle[row_number-1][number-1]+triangle[row_number-1][number])
            triangle[row_number].append(1)
        return triangle
def difference_between_rows(row, next_row):
    row_len = 0
    next_row_len = 0
    for number in row:
        string_number = str(number)
        row_len += (len(string_number)+1)
    for number in next_row:
        string_number = str(number)
        next_row_len += (len(string_number)+1)
    return (next_row_len-1) - (row_len-1)
def print_pascals_triangle(triangle):
    largest_element = triangle[-1][len(triangle[-1]) // 2]
    element_width = len(str(largest_element))
    def format_row(row):
        return ' '.join([str(element).center(element_width) for element in row])
    triangle_width = len(format_row(triangle[-1]))
    for row in triangle:
        print(format_row(row).center(triangle_width))
if __name__ == '__main__':
        rows = 51
        print_pascals_triangle(generate_pascals_triangle(rows))
```

Comment: Please provide your code as a listing instead of image.

Comment: Done, It was giving me trouble posting it as such earler

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried storing each output in a list?